# Get application version name using adb

Tags: android, adb

Is there an easy way to get the version name of an application on an Android device using adb shell?

I found the application version number (not the version name) in /data/system/packages.xml.

It would be nice if there was a file that contained the Application Info.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

```
adb shell dumpsys package my.package | grep versionName
```

as mentioned by [@david](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230825/david) and [@Jeremy Fishman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350436/jeremy-fishman). This will be much quicker than:

```
adb shell dumpsys | grep -A18 "Package \[my.package\]"
```

Comment: That does show me the package info but for some reason it is missing the version information for any package I have tried to look up on my tablet (android 2.2).  On my phone all the version information is there (android 2.3).

Comment: well if you insist doing it in adb, you can do: adb shell service call package 1 s16 "my.package" i32 0. the version number will be somewhere near 0x1F and the name string after 0x20 (should be 3rd line)

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys package my.package` can be significantly quicker

Comment: `dumpsys package my.package | grep versionName` works perfect

Comment: @david but sometimes it returns multiple results, e.g. `adb shell dumpsys package com.google.android.apps.photos | grep versionName
` because of the `Hidden system packages:` section. Maybe a `head -n1` would solve it...

Comment: When using `grep version` instead of `grep versionName` you also get the minSDK, targetSDK and the version code.

Comment: If on Windows, replace `grep` with `findstr`

Answer (score 29):

Dumpsys package is your friend

```
~/# adb shell
shell@mo:/ dumpsys package tld.comp.app_name | grep version
```

Will return

```
versionCode=X targetSdk=YY
versionName=Z.Z
```

Answer (score 14):

In case someone needs all apps versions for comparing purposes then here is my oneliner:

```
for p in `adb shell pm list package | awk -F"package:" '{print $2}'`; do echo -n "$p: "; adb shell dumpsys package $p | grep -i versionName | awk -F"=" '{print $2}'; done
```

Maybe it will be helpful for somebody but please note that I use versionName and ignore versionCode, so use with care.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to get all package versions, try this awk script:

```
adb shell dumpsys package | awk '/^[ ]*Package \[.*\] (.*)/ { i = index($0, "[") + 1; pkg = substr($0, i, index($0, "]") - i); } /[ ]*versionName=/ { { print pkg "\t" substr($0, index($0, "=") + 1); pkg = ""; } }'
```

Comment: NICE! This is a much faster way then the one in @LLL's answer

Comment: 在这个命令后面可以| grep 想要的包名

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want install *.apk on device but you need get version of app, you can do it as follow

```
$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt dump badging app/build/outputs/apk/app.app
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know both the versionCode and versionName of your package's installed versions/flavors, use something like

```
adb shell dumpsys package | 
awk '/^[ ]*Package \[.*\] (.*)/ { i = index($0, "[") + 1; pkg = substr($0, i, index($0, "]") - i); printf "\n%s", pkg; } /[ ]*versionName=/ { { printf "\t%s", $0; } }  /[ ]*versionCode=/ { { printf  "\t%s", $0; } } ' | 
grep my.package
```

to return something like

```
my.package.foo         versionCode=5 minSdk=21 targetSdk=33    versionName=1.2.2
my.package.foo.debug   versionCode=7 minSdk=22 targetSdk=33    versionName=1.2.2 (dev)
...
```

(Building on @user541686's and @MonoThreaded's answers)