# Is package version and app version are different things in android

Tags: android, adb

I am testing the MXplayer. To report the error or any thing i want to return the version number of player, how do I get the version number using adb in android? Is there any difference between the package version and app version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bot terms can be used interchangeably to refer to the same thing - an Android application. Additionally the term "package" can be used to refer to `.APK` file containing the application or to the Java package name of the application.

The term "app name" is usually used to refer to the human readable name like "My Coolest App". Whereas "package name" would be a Java package name like "com.vendorname.mycoolestapp".

But as far as versioning is concerned - both are the same:

```
dumpsys package <package_name> | grep versionName
```

Answer (score 1):

For the package/application [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942762/get-application-version-name-using-adb) use:

```
adb shell dumpsys | grep -A18 "Package \[my.package\]"
```

Comment: have you just suggested to run dumpsys on ALL services just to pull a single package info? depending on a device this could take a few minutes.

Comment: Yeah, seems to be quite heavy sometimes, as you said, depending on the device.