# Get application version name using adb for several devices

Tags: python, android, shell, adb

Is there an easy way to get the version name of an application on Android devices using adb shell?

I've already find this command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942762/get-application-version-name-using-adb):

```
adb shell dumpsys package my.package | grep versionName
```

But I don't know how can I use it for more that one device?!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run an `adb` command on multiple devices in my experience but if you have multiple devices then `adb` command  to run on specific devices becomes as follows:

`adb [-d|-e|-s <serialNumber>] <command>`

- -d means run on the connected device (results in error for more than one connected device)
- -e means run on the simulator (results in error for more than one simulator)
- -s means use specific serial number

serial number used in -s is obtained with `adb devices` command.
a sample output of this command is:

```
List of devices attached
cf264b8f    device
emulator-5554   device
```

for no device connected the first line is only printed

Output format is `[serialNumber] [state]`, serialNumber that is, we often say that the SN, state the following categories:

`Offline`: indicates that the device is not connected to the success or unresponsive.

`Device`: device is connected. Note that this state does not identify the Android system has been fully activated and operational in the device during startup device instance can be connected to the adb, but after boot the system before it becomes operational.

`No device`: no device / emulator connection.

Comment: Thanks for your response mohsen but here is a command I found that executed adb for several devices:
path to app/adb devices | awk 'NR>1{print $1}' | xargs -n1 -I% adb -s % install app.apk

Comment: awk is an advanced text stream command, i thought u needed one adb command to achieve that :). and this command is actually executing multiple adb command not one