# How to display my device Infomation on cmd(using adb)

Tags: android, batch-file, cmd, command-line-interface, adb

I want make batch file using adb and prompt

For instance: I need Huawei P40 info from batch:

```
P40
Model : ANA-AN00
OS : 12
Build Type : User
Build Number : P40Blahblahblah
sdk version : blahblah
```

like this.
I can saw on `adb` (`adb shell getprop ro.blahblah`)
but I can't make to batch file.
I weak to CLI...
pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grep the values returns by `adb shell getprop` as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50156692/6309).

For each value, you can set it in a variable, and then print it with the format you want.

Example:

```
model=$(adb shell getprop | grep model | cut -d ":" -f 2)
# Or, simpler
model=$(adb shell getprop ro.product.model)
echo "model='${model}'"
```

---

The [OP 강승오](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19763855/%EA%B0%95%EC%8A%B9%EC%98%A4) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354700/how-to-display-my-device-infomation-on-cmdusing-adb/73354735#comment129558499_73354735):

> I got app ver from '`adb shell dumpsys package mypackage | grep"'versionName="`' and I checked I want to display `App ver : 1.2.345` but, displayed on result `App ver : versionName=1.2.345`.
> how to solve this?
> I tried `set str` command `set str:%str:versionName=:%` after then nothing displayed on app ver `app ver :` (blank).

If you have set that result to a variable, you can replace the part you don't want:

```
res=$(adb shell dumpsys package mypackage | grep"'versionName=")
res=${res/versionName=/}
echo "res='${res}'
```

Comment: So nice, but I solved. Thx VonC!
I will use temp variable
But your Answer is so nice help to me!

Comment: @강승오 Great, well done!

Comment: Um... Mr.VonC
I have a question
Can you answer it?
I wanna check app ver without " | grep" command

Comment: @강승오 Try `adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk`. It depends on what "version" you want though.

Comment: Um... I mean. I need a specific app ver.
Third Party App. for example chrome, firefox, WeChat etc

Comment: @강승오 Then you need to process `adb shell dumpsys package`, as explained in "[Get application version name using adb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56313536/6309)"

Comment: OK I will try later.
here is 6 AM lol
Thx VonC!

Comment: @강승오 No problem. Have a good (late) night.

Comment: my batch console almost complete.
but, I can't solve last problem.
I got app ver from 'adb shell dumpsys package mypackage  | grep"'versionName="'

and I checked
I want to display
App ver : 1.2.345
but, displayed on result
App ver : versionName=1.2.345

how to solve this?
I tried set str command
set str:%str:versionName=:%

after then nothing displayed on app ver
app ver : (blank)

Comment: @강승오 I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: I tried, but if i add your command, my batch do not work.
maybe I misunderstand.

I'm using now
`for /f %%C IN ('adb shell "dumpsys package org.mozilla.firefox  | grep 'versionName='"') do set appver=%%C`

and how to modify?
Delete all command and change to your command?
I'm confused sry. I'm so stupid